# OneDrive Sync using command line

Tags: onedrive

How to sync files to one drive automatically from terminal/command line and also get a success or failure message after uploading

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: I tried searching for an API for this, couldn't find one. I wrote a script which zips my project and moves it into the one drive folder but that still doesn't tell me if the sync was successful or not